# Using dynamic memory allocation with C++ Libraries

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use Alglib's spline functions and in order to do that I have to initialize an array with my data and pass it in to Alglib's spline function.

I keep getting n_c has to be a constant error. Is there any way around this? I'm already using vector for points. The size wont change when I'm building my spline.

```
void Connector::UniformSpacing(int n)
{
    double arcL = Length();
    double ds = arcL / ((double)n);
    static const int n_c = points.size();
    alglib::real_1d_array x[n_c]; // Error here, n_c is still not a constant

    alglib::spline1dbuildcubic()
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<alglib::real_1d_array> x(n_c)` instead. If you need the address of the internal array you can use `x.data()`.

Comment: Firstly, this has nothing to do with the fact that you are using a type from a library, you could substitute the `real_1d_array` with any other type. Then, apart from the fact that this doesn't work like that, you also seem to be allocating an array of `alglib::real_1d_array`s. Do you really need an array of arrays?

Answer (score 3):

Just because the variable is a `static const` object on the stack doesn't mean that it is a compile-time constant: the variable is initialized at run-time when the function is first called. However, for a built-in array the size needs to known at compile-time. You can make it a `constexpr` in which case the compiler will refuse to compile the initialization unless it can be figured out during compile-time.

The easiest way to use a run-time size is to use

```
std::vector<alglib::real_1d_array> x(n_c);
```

For this type it isn't necessary to know the size at compile-time.

Comment: So how do we use libraries like alglib if we cannot dynamically allocate arrays? Say I read in a bunch of points from a text file and I want to compute the spline around those points? I don't know how many points I need before my program is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

n_c must be compile time constant.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an array whose size can only be specified at runtime, you need to use one of the myriad dynamically sizeable constructs. Depending on whether or not you want to pass ownership of this newly allocated array to the calling library, use one of these two constructs:

```
std::unique_ptr<alglib::real_1d_array[]> x(new alglib::real_1d_array[n_c]);
```

1. Pass ownership to calling library function(say `libfunc`) - You would call `release` on the `unique_ptr` and call as follows : `libfunc(x.release())`.
2. Retain ownership - `libfunc(x.get())`.

Of course, in the "Retain ownership" case, the assumption is that the library won't free this memory.

Comment: Surely, you meant to use `std::unique_ptr<alglib::real_1d_array[]> x(new alglib::real_1d_array[n_c]);` as your version has just one element rather than array.